# Minimum Spanning Tree with Boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I have the following code that generates an undirected graph:

```
// --- Header File ---
class Node { ... };
struct Edge { float weight; };
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, Node, Edge> Grafo;

class MST
{
    public:
        MST(std::vector<Node> nodes);
        Grafo g;
        vector<edge_t> build();
};

// --- cpp File ---
MST::MST(std::vector<Node> nodes) {  // build the graph by setting vertices and edges...  }

vector<edge_t> MST::build()
{
    vector<edge_t> mst;
    kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree(g, std::back_inserter(mst));
    return mst;
}
```

The problem is in the line that I call Kruskal: `kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree()`. If I comment this line it will compile fine, and I can export the graph with graphviz (you can see the graph at [webgraphviz.com](http://www.webgraphviz.com)):

```
graph G {
0[label="a"];
1[label="b"];
2[label="c"];
3[label="d"];
4[label="e"];
0--1 [label=80.4487381];
0--2 [label=406.060333];
0--3 [label=405.738831];
0--4 [label=434.203857];
1--2 [label=25.9422436];
1--3 [label=210.344955];
1--4 [label=246.965591];
2--3 [label=35.805027];
2--4 [label=35.1283379];
3--4 [label=167.5858];
}
```

But if I try to compile with that line I get A LOT of errors from Boost (I'm using g++ 4.9.2). The first error is: `error: forming reference to void typedef value_type& reference;`, this error repeats several times. Other error that appears:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'get(boost::edge_weight_t, const boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Symbol, Edge>&)'
        get(edge_weight, g));
```

So I've tried to add `get(edge_weight, g);` before call the Kruskal method, but I got notes saying:

```
note:   types 'boost::subgraph<Graph>' and 'const boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Symbol, Edge>' have incompatible cv-qualifiers
        get(edge_weight, g));
```

and

```
note:   mismatched types 'const boost::two_bit_color_map<IndexMap>' and 'boost::edge_weight_t'
        get(edge_weight, g));
```

I don't know what to do. This is the first time I'm using Boost Graph Library. It is very powerful but not easy to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**: use

```
kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree(g, std::back_inserter(mst), 
                        weight_map( get(&Edge::weight, g) );
```

**Original answer**:

The problem you are facing is that the algorithm needs to access a graph's weight map and yours doesn't have one by default. If you look at the signature of the algorithm in [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.html) you can see that it is:

```
template <class Graph, class OutputIterator, class P, class T, class R>
OutputIterator kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree(Graph& g, OutputIterator tree_edges, 
                                   const bgl_named_params<P, T, R>& params = all defaults);
```

It has two "normal" parameters (the ones you used) and then a strange looking `bgl_named_params<P, T, R>& params`. This last parameter allows you to use the four parameters listed later in that page: `weight_map`, `rank_map`, `predecessor_map` and `vertex_index_map`. If you don't use any of these parameters its default value is used and in the case of `weight_map` this default is `get(edge_weight,g)`. That only works if you have an interior edge_weight property in your graph, meaning your graph is defined like this:

```
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, 
                    property<vertex_name_t,char>,//Could also be `Node` unless you use another algorithm with requirements on the vertices
                    property<edge_weight_t,float> 
                  > InternalPropGraph;
```

But if that definition was required to use `kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree` (or any other algorithm) then [bundled properties](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html) wouldn't be useful at all. You just need to override the default `weight_map` using the named parameters:

```
//typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, Node, Edge> Grafo;
...
kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree(g, std::back_inserter(mst), 
                        weight_map( get(&Edge::weight, g) );
```

In order to access a property map that relates a vertex/edge descriptor with a member of your structs you can simply use `get(&Struct::member, g)`.

A final note about Named Parameters, if in your invocation of the algorithm you need to use more than one of these parameters, you need to concatenate them with `.` instead of the usual `,` since in the signature `params` despite its name is a single parameter.

```
//the order of the named params is irrelevant
kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree(g, std::back_inserter(mst), 
                                 weight_map(my_weights)
                                .vertex_index_map(my_indices)
                                .predecessor_map(my_predecessors));
```

[Here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DGEBVM9SHBl6ovZ9) is an example that shows something similar to what you want using both internal properties and bundled properties. It deliberately uses different ways to set/access properties to show what you can do.

Comment: It worked. Now I got the idea about 'property declaration'. You gave me a Boost lesson, thank you so much.